# What is the name of the glacial cave containing two frost atronachs, and how do we teleport to that location?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I remember there's a cave in the North of Skyrim on a small island if I am not mistaken and there are two frost atronachs that are not summoned by anyone and you must fight them. I think it's part of a quest. What's the name of the cave and how do you teleport to it through console command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably thinking of The [Chill](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/The_Chill), an unmarked location in Winterhold:

[image: Entrance to The Chill]

It is a prison protected by Frost Atronachs: one is there when entered, and three more appear when leaving the cave.
Maybe you thought it was part of a quest because you committed a crime somewhere in Winterhold and had to fight your way out?

To get there using the console, type `coc WinterholdJail`.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, do you know why the question was downvoted? I thought the question followed guidelines.

Comment: I don't really know, but I assume because it doesn't seem to serve a purpose. If you can add to your answer why you need the information from a gameplay's point of view, that would help.

Comment: Maybe it falls under an identification question based on memory alone.